Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Encryption of root with Dualboot does not work
I wanted to upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS and unfortunately, that broke my Ubuntu system entirely. So I installed Ubuntu from scratch.
I used to have a dualboot setup. Windows 11 and Ubuntu. The Ubuntu partition used to be encrypted.
However, when installing Ubuntu 24.04 LTS there was NO option for encryption of my Ubuntu system. The only option is to erase the whole disk which would delete my Windows installation.
Is there really no option for this setup in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
Kind regards
